# How to get the index from a kendo tabstrip using tabGroup.find()?

Tags: kendo-ui

This is what I am trying to accomplish.

```
var tabIndex = 4; //hard coded NOT WHAT I WANT
var tabStrip = $("#navigationTab").data("kendoTabStrip");            
var item = tabStrip.tabGroup.find(':contains("Billing")');
tabIndex = item.??
 setTabUrl("navigationTab", tabIndex, '@Url.Action(Mvc.Areas.Account.Billing.ActionNames.AccountBilling, Mvc.Areas.Account.Billing.Name, new { id = Model.AccountId })');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tabStrip = $("#navigationTab").data("kendoTabStrip");            
var item = tabStrip.tabGroup.find(':contains("Billing")');
var tabIndex = item.index(); // tabIndex == 4
```